# Devise use different email template in production and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, email-templates

I customized devise email templates under
`views/devise/mailer/` and everything worked fine in development mode.

When I switched to production mode, devise sends email with the default email templates instead of the ones I customized.

Anything that might cause this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by restarting my sidekiq. Apparently sidekiq had a cache of the original email template.